# Difference between two clock hours

Tags: sql, time

So the scenario is as follows, I have two columns
"StartHour" and "EndHour". Both are stored as Integers. 
F.ex values can be StartHour : 30  (clock time 00:30) and EndHour : 630  (clock time 06:30)
The output I'd like from this is 360 (minutes).

I need the difference between the two fields, and I need them in minutes.
I can process the data after I fetch it, but I'd rather not.

Any good ideas?

Comment: It's not helpful, but storing datetimes instead of custom abstractions of same in future would solve this for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use integer aritmethic / (Divide) and % (Modulo)

```
DECLARE @StartHour INT = 30
DECLARE @EndHour INT = 630

SELECT ((@EndHour / 100) * 60 + @EndHour % 100) - ((@StartHour / 100) * 60 + @StartHour % 100)
```